# pgsql copy, quote

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.1,I have to import a csv file into a table,sort it,and export it, the original file and the sorted file all must contain the same data.
I use this

```
 COPY table FROM 'path'
 using  Delimiters ';' Quote '"' CSV;
```

As you can see there is some quoted data,is there a way to maintain them quoted? So when I export the sorted version it has exactly the same data as the original?

```
   so "name1 ; name" -> "name ; name" instead of name ; name
```

EDIT :
I can recover the quotes using Quote '"' on COPY TO

Comment: Interesting.  I don't think so.  The double quotes are part of the CSV format, not the original data.

Comment: I can force quote it all... but since the file must be exactly the same,I don't know what to think about that.

Comment: It would be worth asking where the requirement that the output records must be identically quoted to the input comes from.  A different CSV processing program should not care.  If the requirement is firm, I would be inclined to have a Perl (or equivalent language,) undertake the task.

Comment: it has to be sql, in the original file only few values are quoted, the thing is that the two files must be judged identical afterwards by -diff which can't be done unless the exported file has the quotes also.I guess?